# How to create a list in python when the elements contain commas

Tags: python, list, csv

How do I create a list of strings in python where the strings can contain commas such that the interpreter doesn't break on commas prematurely.

I am reading in a template csv file, created by MSExcel.  The contents are 2 columns: col1 = color, col2 = a sentence that can contain a comma.  The content is as follows:

```
Light Green,"Matches type, instance, etc."
Red,Happens in BD10 but not BD20
Blue,"Instance and time matches, type doesn't match"
Yellow,Caught on replay
```

When I read in and output what was read, it breaks the input line on all commas.

```
#my code snippet, please excuse any typos during sanitization
with open('outfile.csv','r') as infile:
   blah = infile.readlines()
   for i in blah:
      line = i.strip().split(",")
      print line

My output:
['Light Green', '"Matches type', ' instance', ' etc."']
['Red', 'Happens in BD10 but not BD20']
['Blue', '"Instance and time matches', ' type doesn\'t match"']
['Yellow', 'Caught on replay']
```

How do I tell python to ignore commas when it's within "" and break at commas all other times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop the split after the first comma:

```
line = i.strip().split(",", 1)
```

Comment: @brent washburne, this solution IS cool.  Just to be comprehensive, what if the sentence is in col1 and color is in col2, how would I tell python to not break on commas inside the sentence since your trick wouldn't work due to the breaking comma not being in the first occurrence?

Answer (score 4):

python provides tools to parse csv files ... you should use them

```
print list(csv.reader(open("outfile.csv","r")))
```

maybe?

Answer (score 4):

The [cvs module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) makes this easy as pie.

Given:

```
$ cat /tmp/so.csv
Light Green,"Matches type, instance, etc."
Red,Happens in BD10 but not BD20
Blue,"Instance and time matches, type doesn't match"
Yellow,Caught on replay
```

Try:

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/so.csv') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        print line
```

Prints:

```
['Light Green', 'Matches type, instance, etc.']
['Red', 'Happens in BD10 but not BD20']
['Blue', "Instance and time matches, type doesn't match"]
['Yellow', 'Caught on replay']
```